# Proof of nonexistence of a set of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Can there exist a set of 4 square complex matrices $A,B,C,D$ where at least 2 matrices of the four are non-zero, such that for some NxN the following 6 equations are obeyed:

$$A^*D+C^TC^\dagger = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$B^*B+A^TD^\dagger = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$A^*B+A^TC^\dagger = 0 \tag{3}$$
$$A^*D+B^*C^\dagger = 0 \tag{4}$$
$$A^TD+C^TB = 0 \tag{5}$$
$$B^*D+C^TD^\dagger = 0 \tag{6}$$

Where the superscripts $T$ gives the transpose of the matrix, $ * $ turns all elements of the matrix into their complex conjugate and $\dagger$ gives the hermitian adjoint of the matrix which is equivalent to action of both $T$ and $*$ in any order.

I've tried very hard to solve them using gamma matrices in 4x4 but nothing works out. I expect it's impossible. I don't know anything about higher dimensional gamma matices, which representations exist and how they behave under $*,T,\dagger$ perhaps you someone can offer me some helpful insight.

Comment: If you take $A=B=C=D=0$, all equations are satisfied, for any $N\in\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: I think you read over the $\neq 0$ that I totally didn't just edit in hahah

Comment: I just realised I don't mind if at most 2 out of four are non-zero

Comment: It isn’t hard to see that $C$ must be singular in any solution, but I don’t see any easy way to find the general solution. Here are some simple solutions: (1) $A=C=0$ and $B=D=\lambda N$ for some $\lambda\in\mathbb C\setminus0$ and some real nilpotent matrix $N$ of index $2$, (2) $C=D=0$ and $A=B=\lambda N$, (3) $B=C=0$ and $A,D$ are two nonzero real symmetric matrices such that $AD=0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that $A,B,C,D$ are real and symmetric, so that $$A=A^*=A^T=A^\dagger$$
and the same for $B,C,D$. Hence, the equations become

$$AD+C^2 = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$B^2+AD = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$A(B+C) = 0 \tag{3}$$
$$AD+BC = 0 \tag{4}$$
$$AD+CB = 0 \tag{5}$$
$$(B+C)D = 0 \tag{6}$$

Now, take $C=-B$: Equation $3$ and $6$ are satisfied, Equation $1$ and $2$ become the same, and also Equation $4$ and $5$, for any choice of $A,B,D$:
$$AD+B^2 = 0 \tag{1}$$
$$B^2+AD = 0 \tag{2}$$
$$0 = 0 \tag{3}$$
$$AD-B^2 = 0 \tag{4}$$
$$AD-B^2 = 0 \tag{5}$$
$$0 = 0 \tag{6}$$

The problem is now easy to solve: it suffices to take $A,D$ such that $AD=0$, for example the diagonals matrices
$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1 & \\
& 0_{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}\qquad D=\begin{pmatrix}
0 & \\
& 1_{N-1}
\end{pmatrix}$$
and $B=0$.

Comment: $AD\neq 0$. Should the top left entry of $D$ be 0?

Comment: Wow very clever! I'll accept it, the $AD=0$ is straightforward enough

Comment: Yes, sorry for the typo, I edited